# Plotter HP DesignJet T520

Tags: pdf, printing, printer

I have a user that is having issues printer to a T520 designjet in A1.
The printer is set up correctly and has been tested, however on occasion, he receive the following message:  requires to be printed on 840mm but the printer currently using 610mm
And the output is half a page. When printing from another pc, the job prints without problem.
Could there be a setting I have missed when setting up the new computer?